# Split the field value in a mysql JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, split

I've got a column "code" which may have a string of multiple values e.g. "`CODE1&CODE2`"... I just need the first one for my `JOIN` ... kind of like `code.split("&")[0]`

```
SELECT myTable.*, otherTable.id AS theID 
FROM myTable INNER JOIN otherTable 
ON myTable.(+++ code before the & +++) = otherTable.code
```

The value in `myTable` may also just be `CODE1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` will do exactly what you want - return the substring of your column up to the specified character:

```
SELECT 
    myTable.*, 
    otherTable.id AS theID 
FROM myTable 
INNER JOIN otherTable 
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(myTable.code, '&', 1) = otherTable.code
```

More info at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

And here's a fiddle demoing it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96a6e/2

Please note that this will be SLOW if you're joining many columns.  You're not only eliminating the possibility of using an index, but performing a very slow string operation on every comparison.  I wouldn't suggest using this on very large tables.  If your data set is huge, you may want to consider rearchitecting your DB.

Comment: hmmm I get this error: SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name. So it looks like I can't do that anyways... rearchitecting it is.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you on?